# LEGO sealed Bag 3 number 404R8 - lots of light greys

Tags: set-identification

I have a sealed LEGO bag number 3. It has a lot of common gray pieces and tan pieces. Any help with where the pieces go to.

[image: Lego sealed Bag 3 number 404R8 - lots of light greys]

[image: Lego sealed Bag 3 number 404R8 - lots of light greys]

[image: Lego sealed Bag 3 number 404R8 - lots of light greys]

Comment: Hi Christian, the codes on Lego bags can't be used to identify the set. The best way to get help is to upload a photo of the bag.

Comment: I have just uploaded the pictures I needed to size down the pictures from my phone.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's [75210-1 Moloch's Landspeeder](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75210-1)

Based on

- Light Bluish Gray Projectile Launcher Part, Rapid Shooter Trigger
- Light Bluish Gray Technic, Disk 3 x 3
- Tan Brick, Modified 1 x 4 with Studs on Side

[image: 75210-1 Moloch's Landspeeder]